# Can I connect the variables In a table?

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

For an example, lets say I have this table:

```
tbl = {"hi ", "my ", "name ", "is ", "King"}
```

Can I get this to return:

```
"hi my name is King"
```

Without

```
for k, v in ipairs( tbl )
  print(v)
end
```

Because I am trying to process an unknown quantity of inputs, and compare the result to another string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`table.concat()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.concat) to get the result string:

```
local str = table.concat(tbl)
print(str)
```

It can do more, in particular, `table.concat()` takes a second optional parameter, which can be used as the separator, for instance, to use commas to separate each elements:

```
local str = table.concat(tbl, ',')
```

The biggest advantage of `table.concat()` versus direct string concatenation is performance, see [PiL §11.6](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.6.html) for detail.